# Group sequence of integers

Tags: r

I have bunch of observations

`x = c(1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 7, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14)`

that I want to turn into the group:

`y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)`

I.e I want the first `5` integers (1 to 5) to constitute one group, the next `5` integers to constitute the next group (6 to 10), and so on.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this without a loop?

Clarification: I need to programmatically create the groups form the input vector (`x`)

Comment: @akrun, thanks, but I need to programmatically create the groups form the input vector (`x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%/%` to create the group

```
x%/%5+1
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ceiling` to create groups

```
ceiling(x/5)

# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```